# Div scrollTop with jQuery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery scrollTop to toggle a div class. Please see the below code

```
$(".div-two").scroll(function() {

    var useFixedDiv = $(".div-two").scrollTop(100);
    $('.div-two').toggleClass('div-two-fixed', useFixedDiv); 

});
```

This doesn't seems to work. Also i change the line

```
var useFixedDiv = $(".div-two").scrollTop(100);
```

to

```
var useFixedDiv = $(".div-two").scrollTop() > 100;
```

Still no results. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The second version works fine. What is not working exactly?

Comment: it doesn't change the class. That is the issue.

Comment: `useFixedDiv` isn't going to have a class name. Have you double-checked what value it holds?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Swa/

Comment: @dfsq in your demo seems to work. but in my code it doesn't i will check again.